# В чем ошибка в коде (Scanner)?

Tags: java, scanner

Если ввести hello, то он все равно выводит No.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class helloworld
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inp = scan.nextLine();
        if(inp == "hello")
        {
            System.out.println("Yes!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(inp == "hello")` => `if(inp.equals("hello"))`

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том, что оператор == проверяет ссылаются ли две переменные на один и тот же объект. И его стоит применять только при сравнении примитивных типов (int, char, ...). Если вы хотите сравнить объекты, (а вы сравниваете объекты класса String), то нужно использовать метод equals.
поэтому замените строчку

```
if(inp == "hello")
```

на

```
if(inp.equals("hello"))
```